# iOS app to input and sort numbers

Tags: gratis, ios

I am looking for a very simple app in which you can enter integers, for instance:

```
328753252
4398672
309406242
```

Then you press "Sort", and it would sort the numbers.

Requirements:

- Free
- Available on iOS
- Native is preferred (if webapp please also send screenshot as seen on iOS)
- The more lightweight the better

Comment: this one is a web tool http://www.miniwebtool.com/sort-numbers/ (_option for sort numbers in ASC or DESC_)

Comment: @unique_id: Native app would be much better :-)

Comment: I guess it got downvoted because you asked for something near impossible :)